# Perform matrix multiplication with single column * single row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How do I stop python from assuming that I want the scalar result of a dot product?

I have columns taken from two matrices, V=[v1,v2,v3,...] and D=[d1,d2,...] of lengths M and N respectively.
I need the following matrix, which can be generated by matrix multiplication of one column with one row.

v1*d1, v1*d2, v1*d3, ...

v2*d1, v2*d2,

v3*d1,

.
.
.

This calculation will be done at least hundreds of thousands of times so I don't want to use a for-loop.
When I try to do this with numpy it assumes I want the more common dot product (1xM, Nx1) to result in a scalar(if M=N) or error, rather than the (Mx1, 1xN) for the MxN matrix I want.  I've tried np.dot and np.matmul, and in each case it seems to ignore np.transpose.

In the following I've tried to specify that these objects should be considered to have two dimensions, and it gives the same error with or without the presence of transpose.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.arange(4)
d = np.arange(3)
np.reshape(v,(1,4))
np.reshape(d,(3,1))

e = np.matmul(np.transpose(d),v)
print(e)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/voidbender/research/NNs/test2.py", line 8, in 
e = np.matmul(np.transpose(v),d)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 3 is different from 4)

Comment: So you want the matrix product of a (3,1) and (1,4) with the sum-of-products on the common size 1 dimension, and (3,4) result.  `matmul` can do that with the correct paring of shapes.  So can `broadcasted` elementwise multiplication.  `matmul` docs should be clear about how dimensions are paired.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to re-assign v and d to its reshape version, this does the job:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.arange(4)
d = np.arange(3)
v =np.reshape(v,(1,4))
d =np.reshape(d,(3,1))

e=np.matmul(d,v)
print(e)
```

results:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 2 4 6]]
```

Just to make it simpler, and avoid reshape, you can create column and row vectors by:

```
row_vector=np.array([np.arange(4)])
col_vector=np.array([np.arange(3)]).T

e=np.matmul(col_vector,row_vector)
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Comment: Great, upvote it if it was useful! Thanks ;)